# What Does JDK Thread Constructor StackSize means?

Tags: multithreading, java-threads

I set Thread stackSize=1, Then invoke three method. In my opinion, method stack is 3 or more. but why not occur Stackoverflow Exception? this is my code:

```
public class ExecutorsTest {
private static void printOne() {
    System.out.println("do Print One");
    printTwo();
}
private static void printTwo() {
    System.out.println("do Print Two");
    printThree();
}
private static void printThree() {
    System.out.println("do Print Three");
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("thread-Group");
    Thread thread = new Thread(group, ()-> {
        printOne();
    },"myThread",1);
    thread.start();
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Java Virtual Machine thread has a private Java Virtual Machine stack, created at the same time as the thread.

A Java Virtual Machine stack stores frames. The stack holds local variables and partial results, and plays a part in method invocation and return.

The **stack size** is the approximate **number of bytes of address space** that the virtual machine is to allocate for this thread's stack.

> The effect of the `stackSize` parameter, if any, is highly platform dependent.

On some platforms, specifying a higher value for the `stackSize` parameter may allow a thread to achieve greater recursion depth before throwing a `StackOverflowError`.

Similarly, specifying a lower value may allow a greater number of threads to exist concurrently without throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` (or other internal error).

The details of the relationship between the value of the `stackSize` parameter and the maximum recursion depth and concurrency level are platform-dependent.

On some platforms, the value of the `stackSize` parameter may have no effect whatsoever.